# Empty Netbeans 7 palette? How to restore it?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, netbeans-7, palette

I use Netbeans 7 on Kubuntu 12.04. I start Netbeans like this:

```
netbeans --cp:a /usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar &
```

cause of known issue with Netbeans and Kubuntu 12.04. In the middle of my project my palette with Swing components just .. disappeared!

I see only sth like this:

[image]

How to restore default Netbeans palette?

**I checked Ctrl+Shift+8 shortcut but with no results - the problem is still the same.**

**EDIT:
I dont know what I did but now I see ONLY EMPTY palette :( : **

[image]

I also tried this:

1) I cd'ed to `/home/mazix/.netbeans/7.0/config/Windows2Local/Groups/commonpalette`
, ls'ed and saw only this: CommonPalette.wstcgrp

2) cd'ed to `/home/mazix/.netbeans/7.0/config/Windows2Local/Components` and saw this:

> AnalyzerTopComponent.settings            output.settings
>   AnalyzeStackTopComponent.settings        projectTabLogical_tc.settings
>   breakpointsView.settings                 projectTab_tc.settings
>   CallHierarchyTopComponent.settings       properties_1.settings
>   callstackView.settings                   properties.settings
>   CommonPalette.settings                   refactoring-preview.settings
>   ComponentInspector.settings
>   ReporterResultTopComponent.settings CssPreviewTC.settings
>   resultsView.settings debugging.settings
>   search-results.settings DeclarationTopComponent.settings
>   services.settings evaluator.settings
>   sessionsView.settings favorites.settings
>   sources.settings find-usages.settings
>   StyleBuilderTC.settings gsf-testrunner-results.settings
>   svnversioning.settings hgversioning.settings
>   synchronize.settings JavadocTopComponent.settings
>   TaskListTopComponent.settings localsView.settings
>   TerminalContainerTopComponent.settings
>   MultiView-java#007Cform#007C_1.settings  threadsView.settings
>   MultiView-java#007Cform#007C_2.settings  versioning_output.settings
>   MultiView-java#007Cform#007C_4.settings  watchesView.settings
>   MultiView-java#007Cform#007C.settings    Welcome.settings
>   navigatorTC.settings

and didnt see any  _hidden files :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open NetBeans and choose Window -> Palette 
It will appear but it will be empty because you didn't choose a GUI class yet.

To fill the palette with the GUI components like labels, follow these steps:

1. Create a new project .
2. Right click in the package name or project name, and choose New -> Other...
3. In the New File dialog box, choose the "Swing GUI Forms" from category and the "JFrame" 
   Form file type sub window. Click Next.
4. Enter name lets say "MyGUI" for the new the class which you created now.
5. The palette window is now full with components like labels, text,checkboxes, ...

if not appear yet make sure to press "Design" button in the upper of the GUI class bar "MyGUI"class

Comment: Some netbeans versions might have it on Window -> IDE Tools -> Palette.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue and this work for me window -> reset window. hope it work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the same problem occur here.Check this [solution](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic41046.html).it may helpful to you.

This steps for restore the default palette?

1. Exit the IDE.
2. Go to your user directory and go down to config/Palette subdir. In this directory, the files or directories deleted from the default palette content are presented as empty files with _hidden suffix in their names.
3. Delete these _hidden files to let the palette categories and items appear again in the IDE.

I think this will help you

Comment: Nope, it didnt help at all. I switched to Design View but it didnt help, I also used `-clean` option to start Netbeans, also with no results.

Comment: geez now I see only empty palette and I did ... nothig :/

Comment: Do you want steps for restore default Netbeans palette?

Comment: thanks but it didnt help too. Please see my edit and thank you for helping:)

Comment: Thanks for your information.It helpful for me too and others also.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing, simply right click on your netbeans project and then open it. It resolves the problem. You will observe if u open a new project the palette is there, so just copy the project with a different name, its will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after creating a new project without a default constructor, the search box at the palette holds a single character i.e. '='. this results in an empty palette too.

In that case the solution is obvious: just delete the content of the search input.
It puzzled me for a moment, though, not noticing the search input field content.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation with my netbeans. The only solution I did was to backup my project folder (saving it to other drive). Then re-install the netbeans. Afterwards I re-paste the project folder at the directory and re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click mouse button at palette box. Choose command "reset palette".

Comment: Now it's even more emtpy then before.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Just check the bottom of the palette to see if there is a search box open. If there is, close it. Then the palette will be available once again.

Answer (score 0):

So, nothing suggested here worked for me, I am leaving my solution.
You create the project, name it.
Create a package.
Click on the package with the right mouse button
select New filme
select Other
select AWT GUI Forms
select Frame form
Now you should see the menu at the right part of your screen with the option to create buttons, labels, etc.

Answer (score -1):

As of 2021 for mac users;

1. Open your NetBeans app and click on "windows" located at the top menu of the application. A drop down will appear.
2. Scroll down and click "IDE Tools". You'll see another dropdown containing list of items including palette.
3. Click on the "palette". This will make the palette visible.

That's all!