# Why is the palette in NetBeans appearing blank?

Tags: java, netbeans

I installed Apache NetBeans 11. Correctly I think. But when I want to use the palette it appears blank without components. How can that be fixed?

Comment: I think that you can find the answer of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405491/empty-netbeans-7-palette-how-to-restore-it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty Netbeans 7 palette? How to restore it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405491/empty-netbeans-7-palette-how-to-restore-it)